# Incorrect message with GET_ACCOUNTS permission

Tags: android, android-permissions, google-account, android-6.0-marshmallow

Am trying to update my app with the new Android M permissions which uses Google+ login, but when I do a `checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS)` the dialog that pops up says "Allow MyApp to access your contacts?" with the Deny and Allow buttons.

This seems kind of weird for the GET_ACCOUNTS permission. Shouldn't it say something related to access your accounts instead? Is this a bug? Or should I be doing something differently?

Comment: It is by design, but baffling design.  The contact permissions are extremely important - usually protecting the private data of hundreds of people.  Having to ask the user for that, in order to use GET_ACCOUNTS, makes no sense - the user should not accept that.

Answer (score 5):

The GET_ACCOUNTS permission is part of the android.permission-group.CONTACTS group, along with the

- android.permission.READ_CONTACTS
- android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS
- android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS

This is why you get the message for CONTACTS.

So when you ask for one permission in a group, you will get all of them in that group.
You can find more information about permission in Android M [here](https://developer.android.com/preview/features/runtime-permissions.html)

Comment: hmm.. thats weird.  so  if we were asking for GET_ACCOUNTS permission seems misleading to users to say we are trying to read contacts.  no?

Comment: Well, that's why Google made the shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale method, so you can explain yourself to the user why you ask a certain permission

Comment: I do have that but seems it is not called and seems Android determines if it should show it or not. So :(

Comment: Yes, so you should implement it. I have implemented and it works great. Also, I found this article helpful   https://plus.google.com/u/0/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/FqgHUevqHiK?pid=6190365492807007074&oid=108967384991768947849

Comment: This is a very poor implementation by Google. They try to group permissions, so the user doesn't have to give access for every individual permission. But in this case, the grouping just doesn't make sense. You might be asking for access to user's google drive account, that has nothing to do with contacts, and the shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale() will only show up once they Deny the request.

Comment: It's even worse, it asks for the group, but you still need to ask permission for every other permission in that group. REALLY bad user experience. He thinks we are asking the same thing over and over.

Comment: I don't think this is what happends. Check this out, from the documentation: "For example, suppose you list both READ_CONTACTS and WRITE_CONTACTS in your app manifest. If you request READ_CONTACTS and the user grants the permission, and you then request WRITE_CONTACTS, the system immediately grants you that permission without interacting with the user."

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend moving away from Google+ login and using the new Google login.  It requires no special permissions to access email and can be easily integrated.

https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start

Answer (score -1):

I was updating a client's app this afternoon which allows users to login with Google+. You might not need to check the GET_ACCOUNTS permission at runtime. I updated the manifest to qualify the GET_ACCOUNTS permission with `android:maxSdkVersion="22"`.

On a Nexus 5 running Marshmallow I was able to successfully login using Google+ without displaying a runtime permissions dialog. Nor does Contacts appear in Settings>Apps>[my client's app]>Permissions.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS" android:maxSdkVersion="22"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" android:maxSdkVersion="22"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_ACCOUNTS" android:maxSdkVersion="22"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" android:maxSdkVersion="22"/>
```

Documentation for GET_ACCOUNTS reflecting change of behaviour in Marshmallow is described [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#GET_ACCOUNTS).

Comment: are there any side effects to specifying the `maxSdkVersion` in the Manifest tihs way?

Comment: Don't believe so no. On Marshmallow you should be prompting for GET_ACCOUNTS permission at runtime if you need to access any accounts created by an App with a different signature than your own.

Comment: Don't use maxSdkVersion 22. This means that no Marshmallow device will see your app in Play Store.

Comment: @Timur_C the maxSdkVersion of 22 should be used as an attribute of <uses-permission>, rather than as the App's maxSdkVersion else you are correct the Play Store will limit distribution of the App to pre-Marshmallow devices.

Comment: OK then how could you access accounts on Marshmallow without the permission? AFAIK if you set max SDK for a permission it doesn't work on newer versions.

Comment: If you set maxSdkVersion on a uses-permission then it isn't granted for newer SDK's unless that SDK supports runtime permissions and you call the appropriate API at runtime to grant that permission.